# How do you branch a single file from a multi-file project in bazaar?

Tags: application-development, launchpad, bazaar

How do you branch a single file from a multi-file project in bazaar?

For example:

lp:ubuntu-popey-app has two files; `foo.h` and `bar.h` 

I would do something like this:

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-popey-app --file "/src/foo.h"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bzr cat`, example :

```
$ bzr cat lp:~ubuntu-clock-dev/ubuntu-clock-app/utopic-3.0/app/ubuntu-clock-app.qml > ubuntu-clock-app.qml
```

To get a binary file :

```
$ bzr cat lp:~ubuntu-art-pkg/ubuntu-themes/trunk/distributor-logo.png  > distributor-logo.png
```

To get the content of a folder, you can combine `bzr ls -R` and `bzr cat` to replicate the folder

```
$ bzr ls -R lp:~ubuntu-clock-dev/ubuntu-clock-app/utopic-3.0/backend/
CMakeLists.txt                                                                                                                                  
modules/
modules/Alarm/
modules/Alarm/Settings/
modules/Alarm/Settings/alarmsettings.cpp
modules/Alarm/Settings/alarmsettings.h
modules/Alarm/Settings/backend.cpp
modules/Alarm/Settings/backend.h
modules/Alarm/Settings/qmldir
modules/DateTime/
modules/DateTime/backend.cpp
modules/DateTime/backend.h
modules/DateTime/datetime.cpp
modules/DateTime/datetime.h
modules/DateTime/qmldir
modules/GeoLocation/
modules/GeoLocation/backend.cpp
modules/GeoLocation/backend.h
modules/GeoLocation/geolocation.cpp
modules/GeoLocation/geolocation.h
modules/GeoLocation/qmldir
modules/Timezone/
modules/Timezone/backend.cpp
modules/Timezone/backend.h
modules/Timezone/generictimezonemodel.cpp
modules/Timezone/generictimezonemodel.h
modules/Timezone/jsontimezonemodel.cpp
modules/Timezone/jsontimezonemodel.h
modules/Timezone/qmldir
modules/Timezone/timezonemodel.cpp
modules/Timezone/timezonemodel.h
modules/Timezone/xmltimezonemodel.cpp
modules/Timezone/xmltimezonemodel.h
tests/
tests/unit/
```